# Configure SSO on Worklight 6.2

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst

I was reviewing on how to implement the SSO through the following URL:

http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/#!/SSZH4A_6.2.0/com.ibm.worklight.dev.doc/devref/t_configuring_device_SSO.html

Matching with our code, the authenticationConfig.xml is implemented to be the following:

```
<customSecurityTest name="BankingTestMobile">
            <test realm="wl_antiXSRFRealm" step="2"/>
            <test realm="wl_authenticityRealm" step="2"/>
            <test realm="wl_remoteDisableRealm" step="2"/>
            <test realm="wl_directUpdateRealm" mode="perSession" step="1"/>
            <test realm="wl_anonymousUserRealm" isInternalUserID="true" step="2"/>
            <test realm="wl_deviceNoProvisioningRealm" isInternalDeviceID="true" step="2"/>
            <test realm="MySSO" isInternalUserID="true" step="3"/>
</customSecurityTest>
```

Realm:

```
<realm loginModule="BankingLoginModule" name="BankingRealm">
            <className>com.worklight.integration.auth.AdapterAuthenticator</className>
            <parameter name="login-function" value="MBCAuthenticationAdapter.onAuthRequired" />
            <parameter name="logout-function" value="MBCAuthenticationAdapter.onLogout" />
</realm>
```

Login Module:

```
    <loginModule name="BankingLoginModule" ssoDeviceLoginModule="WLDeviceNoProvisioningLoginModule">
                <className>com.worklight.core.auth.ext.NonValidatingLoginModule</className> 
</loginModule>
```

My question is in the `<customSecurityTest>`. From where the SSO realm is getting picked up? What the realm name should be for SSO?

Do I need to define a realm for it?

I'm not sure how the configuration actually should be done on the `<customSecurityTest>` where in the `<mobileSecurityTest>` it is clear.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you should change the `<test realm="MySSO"` ... to `"BankingRealm"` (or the vice versa).

Also see here: [App will throw exception at when I first login when device SSO is enabled](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30711900/app-will-throw-exception-at-when-i-first-login-when-device-sso-is-enabled)

Comment: That was my assumption too. Thanks Idan. Is it ok to have "isInternalUserID" twice? the one for SSO and the other for "wl_anonymousUserRealm"?