# Device Single sign on is not working when used with adapter authenticator which is wl_unprotected

Tags: single-sign-on, ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-adapters, worklight-server, worklight-security

I am testing device SSO using mobile security test and I have used Adapter authentication. I have created two apps in a same project and my `authenicationConfig.xml` looks something like this

```
 <staticResources>
    <resource id="subscribeServlet" securityTest="SubscribeServlet">
        <urlPatterns>/subscribeSMS*;/receiveSMS*;/ussd*</urlPatterns>
    </resource>
</staticResources>  

 <securityTests>
           <mobileSecurityTest name="AuthSecurityTest">
        <testDeviceId provisioningType="none" />
        <testUser realm="AuthRealm" sso="true" />
    </mobileSecurityTest>
</securityTests> 

<realms>

    <realm loginModule="AuthLoginModule" name="AuthRealm">
        <className>com.worklight.integration.auth.AdapterAuthenticator</className>
        <parameter name="login-function" value="AuthAdapter.onAuthRequired"/>
        <parameter name="logout-function" value="AuthAdapter.onLogout"/>
    </realm>

    <realm name="SampleAppRealm" loginModule="StrongDummy">
        <className>com.worklight.core.auth.ext.FormBasedAuthenticator</className>
    </realm>

    <realm name="SubscribeServlet" loginModule="rejectAll">
        <className>com.worklight.core.auth.ext.HeaderAuthenticator</className>          
    </realm>

</realms>

<loginModules>
    <loginModule name="AuthLoginModule">
        <className>com.worklight.core.auth.ext.NonValidatingLoginModule</className>
    </loginModule>

    <loginModule name="StrongDummy" expirationInSeconds="3600">
        <className>com.worklight.core.auth.ext.NonValidatingLoginModule</className>
    </loginModule>

    <loginModule name="requireLogin" expirationInSeconds="3600">
        <className>com.worklight.core.auth.ext.SingleIdentityLoginModule</className>
    </loginModule>

    <loginModule name="rejectAll" expirationInSeconds="3600">
        <className>com.worklight.core.auth.ext.RejectingLoginModule</className>
    </loginModule>

</loginModules>
```

### AuthAdapter.xml:

```
<procedure name="submitAuthentication" securityTest="wl_unprotected" />
    <procedure name="getSecretData" securityTest="AuthSecurityTest"/>
    <procedure name="getSecretData2" securityTest="AuthSecurityTest"/>
```

The above `getSecretdata` is called from app1 and  `getSecretdata` is called from app2.

### AuthAdapter.js:

```
function onAuthRequired(headers, errorMessage){
    errorMessage = errorMessage ? errorMessage : null;

    return {
        authStatus: "credentialsRequired",
        errorMessage: errorMessage
    };
}

function submitAuthentication(username, password){
    if (username==="user" && password === "password"){

        var userIdentity = {
                userId: username,
                displayName: username, 
                attributes: {
                    foo: "bar"
                }
        };

        WL.Server.setActiveUser("AuthRealm", userIdentity);

        return { 
            authStatus: "complete" 
        };
    }

    return onAuthRequired(null, "Invalid login credentials");
}

function getSecretData(){
    return {
        secretData: "Very very very very secret data"
    };
}
function getSecretData2(){
    return {
        secretData: "Very very very very secret data222222222222222222"
    };
}
function onLogout(){
    WL.Logger.debug("Logged out");
}
```

Can anyone tell me what am I doing wrong. How can I access second app without logging in.

I did read the question posted in [App will throw exception at when I first login when device SSO is enabled](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30711900/app-will-throw-exception-at-when-i-first-login-when-device-sso-is-enabled) but did not get a clear picture about `Authadapter.xml`. Also how do I enable SSO for `wl_unprotected` security test?

I get the following error in the Worklight console when I try to after logging in.

> [ERROR ] FWLSE0059E: Login into realm 'AuthLoginModule' failed. Stream unable to set size. [project DSSO] Stream unable to set size
>   [ERROR ] FWLSE0117E: Error code: 4, error description: AUTHENTICATION_ERROR, error message: An error occurred while performing authentication using loginModule AuthLoginModule, User Identity Not available. [project DSSO] [project DSSO]

I am trying out Worklight Device SSO for the first time

Comment: I finally got it working. All I had to do was to mention the security test inside application-descriptor file. ;)

Answer (score 2):

The security test needs to be mentioned in the application-descriptor.xml

For iPhone:

`<iphone bundleId="com.asdasf" version="1.0" securityTest="AuthSecurityTest">`

For Android:

`<android version="1.0" securityTest="AuthSecurityTest">`